# Map labels to counts after tf.unique_with_counts()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a BxN input feature tensor `feature_labels` and I call

```py
unique_labels, label_idcs, label_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(feature_labels)
```

to get the label counts.

How do I produce a BxN matrix, which stores the label counts instead of the labels?

**Example for one batch:**

```
Input: 
feature_labels: 0 1 1 1 0 2 3 1 3

> unique_labels, _, label_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(feature_labels)

=> unique_labels: 0 1 2 3
=> label_counts: 2 4 1 2

Output:
2 4 4 4 2 1 2 4 2
```

Comment: Please show an input example and the output you would expect for it, currently it is not clear what matrix you want to get.

Comment: @jdehesa added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    feature_labels = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3], tf.int32)
    _, unique_idx, label_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(feature_labels)
    result = tf.gather(label_counts, unique_idx)
    print(sess.run(result))
    # [2 4 4 4 2 1 2 4 2]
```

Comment: To make it work on the BxN matrices I had to use `tf.python.ops.gen_array_ops.unique_with_counts_v2(feature_labels, axis=[-1])`, but apart from that it works, thanks.